# symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 opencv xcode 4.4.1 osx lion

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv

excuse me... I'm using xcode 4.4.1 and macbook pro 2011 early which is it's running on osx lion 64 bit...

I get these following error while compiling...

```
   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_gzclose", referenced from:
      _cvReleaseFileStorage in OpenCV(persistence.o)
      _cvOpenFileStorage in OpenCV(persistence.o)
   "_gzeof", referenced from:
  __ZL6icvEofP13CvFileStorage in OpenCV(persistence.o)


"_gzgets", referenced from:
      __ZL7icvGetsP13CvFileStoragePci in OpenCV(persistence.o)
  "_gzopen", referenced from:
      _cvOpenFileStorage in OpenCV(persistence.o)
  "_gzputs", referenced from:
      __ZL7icvPutsP13CvFileStoragePKc in OpenCV(persistence.o)
  "_gzrewind", referenced from:
      _cvOpenFileStorage in OpenCV(persistence.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

that's happened when I declaring `cv::mat` .... (if i erase it.. it will compile correctly..)
anyone know how to fix this? thx..